# PHP var_dump with soft hyphen in string counts the soft hyphen as 3 characters

Tags: php

I'm working on a custom PHP config file parser. It should convert this line:

```
db.name.external = "test­"
```

into an array:

```
array(1) {
  ["db"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["external"]=>
      string(4) "test"
    }
  }
}
```

If there's a soft hyphen in the value, var_dump returns the wrong string count - it adds +1 to the string length. PHPStorm shows the correct length.

[PHPStorm Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQRyJ.png)

I guess it's an encoding issue, any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at what character actual is?

Comment: The count is the number of bytes, not the number of characters. This is a multi-byte character.

Comment: Why do you care what `var_dump()` shows? As long as the value is correct.